# Spring Boot, Spring Security, MySQL - CustomUserDetailsService always results in the error "Invalid Username or Password"

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

The Problem i have resulted out of [this tutorial](http://www.programming-free.com/2016/01/spring-security-spring-data-jpa.html).

My Problem is that i always run in the issue that my user is read out of the database but i don't get authenticated. On the view it always shows the error message "Invalid Username or Password". My Console-output shows no errors. When i debugged through my authentication process there were no unclear behaviours where the error could come from.

In my pom.xml i used the following dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

My CustomUserDetailsService.java looks like this.

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserRolesRepository userRolesRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository,
            UserRolesRepository userRolesRepository) {

        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.userRolesRepository = userRolesRepository;

    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user present with username " + username);
        }
        else {
            List<String> userRoles = userRolesRepository.findRoleByUserName(username);
            return new CustomUserDetails(user, userRoles);
        }

    }

}
```

CustomUserDetails.java

```
    public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<String> userRoles;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user, List<String> userRoles) {

        super(user);
        this.userRoles = userRoles;

    }

    @Override
    public Collection< ? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        String roles = StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(userRoles);

        return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(roles);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {

        return false;
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/images/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/loadEvents")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder() {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

As i mentioned before i don't think that the error occures on the database. I used the database scheme out of the tutorial. I also used User.java UserRole.java and the two repositories out of the tutorial.

My Application.java looks like this.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "<package>")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "<package>")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Update 1: Link to Git Project** 
https://github.com/pStuetz/Speeddating4SO/tree/master

You maybe have to Edit the src/main/resources/application.properties to support your database. I included the sql script which i used to create my database tables.

Comment: Could you please share your source code? The app from the given tutorial is not working correctly, it complains about missed pages etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i added the link to the git project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've enabled trace logging in application.properties by adding this row

```
logging.level.=TRACE
```

and saw the error message

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException: User account is locked
```

in the console.

Your custom user details class **de.dhbw.stuttgart.speeddating.userhandling.service.impl.CustomUserDetails** returns "**false**" from methods "**isAccountNonExpired**", "**isAccountNonLocked**" and "**isCredentialsNonExpired**". I guess the methods should return the value of the property "**enabled**" from the class **de.dhbw.stuttgart.speeddating.userhandling.service.User**.

After changing all those "false" to "true", the login procedure started to work as expected.

Comment: That's the solution. Thank you very much!